# prices = [ .75, 2.25, 1.50, 3.0, 2.5, .50, .90, .85 3.5] What's the simplest way to return values >= 2 from the list

Tags: python, list

`prices = [ .75, 2.25, 1.50, 3.0, 2.5, .50, .90, .85 3.5]` What's the simplest way to return values `>= 2` from the list.

I seen some code in Github and google but I can't get to work. I'm learning how to code in python 3.

```
prices = [.75, 2.25, 1.50, 3.0, 2.5, .50, .90, .85 3.5]
prince = sorted(i for i in j if i >= 2)
print(j2)
```

I expect this result `[2.25, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5]`

Comment: In python, the easiest way to filter lists is using list comprehensions, have you given it a try? There are plenty of related questions...

Answer (score 0):

```
prices = [.75, 2.25, 1.50, 3.0, 2.5, .50, .90, .85, 3.5]
prince = [item for item in prices if item => 2]
print (sorted(prince))
```

output:

```
[2.25, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5]
```